# The value '-1' cannot be parsed as the type 'Byte'

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a byte Array in a string which I am trying to serialize into an object, the byte array was generated on an iPhone but the receiving service is VB.net I get the error The value '-1' cannot be parsed as the type 'Byte' when the serializer.ReadObject call is made and have managed to get c# to see the byte array as valid using

```
byte[] ba = new byte[] { 208, 125, 138, 15, unchecked((byte)-1), 211, 1, 74, 148, unchecked((byte)-9), 82, 10, 245, 193, 115, 64, 108, 12 };
```

but the unchecked element doesn't appear to exist in VB and I am pulling my hair out as to how to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance

The object is

```
Public Class GetVehicleListInput : Inherits BaseInput

End Class
```

BaseInput is

```
Public Class BaseInput

Private abyteExternalIdentifier As Byte() = Nothing

Public Property ExternalIdentifier() As Byte()
    Get
        Return abyteExternalIdentifier
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Byte())
        abyteExternalIdentifier = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New()

End Sub

End Class
```

My Class is

```
Dim mystring As String = "{""ExternalIdentifier"":[208,125,138,15,-1,211,1,74,148,-9,82,10,245,193,115,64,108,12]}"
    Dim serializer As New Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(GetVehicleListInput))

    Dim thing As GetVehicleListInput
    Using stream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mystring))

        thing = DirectCast(serializer.ReadObject(stream), GetVehicleListInput)
    End Using
 End Sub
```

Comment: You mean the iPhone sends a string literal that is a series of numbers, right?

Comment: it sends the value that is myString

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In .NET world, [`Byte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte(v=vs.110).aspx) values are unsigned, 8-bits integers. Therefore they are limited to be within 0 to 255.

Granted, [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) *does* allow you to suppress the overflow checking, but even so you still won't have the -1 value stored as a [`Byte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte(v=vs.110).aspx): **the value will be 255**.

You might want to use [`Int16`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int16(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, although I'm not sure how this will work out with the serialization / deserialization mechanisms you're using.

Of course you also can use Plutonix's solution, but then I would wonder why you ever had to pass in -1 in the first place.

Comment: SByte is limited to -128 to 127  my first byte value is 208 any others you are aware of?

Comment: @Noreen what about Int16 (Short in VB)?

Answer (score 1):

A byte (in VB.Net or C#) is an 8-bit unsigned integer in the range of 0 to 255.  The key is in the C# code:

```
unchecked((byte)-1) ... unchecked((byte)-9)
```

This suppresses overflow checking and the resulting array is:

[image]

Your code should work using:

```
mystring = ... "[208,125,138,15,255,211,1,74,148,247,82,10,245,193,115,64,108,12]"

' as byte array:
ba As Byte() = {208, 125, 138, 15, 255, 211, 1, 74, 148, 247, 
                 82, 10, 245, 193, 115, 64, 108, 12}
```

Using 255 and 247 in place of the negative values.

---

New info: `I don't have control of the incoming byte array`

The code looks like a literal, but if you are receiving an array of bytes, you wont have negative values in it.  To convert the incoming values to a byte array and apply your overflow check:

```
Dim someVals As Int16() = {208, 125, 138, 15, -1, 211, 1, 74, 148, -9, 
              82, 10, 245, 193, 115, 64, 108, 12}
Dim byteArry(someVals.Count - 1) As Byte

For n As Integer = 0 To someVals.Count - 1

    byteArry(n) = CByte(someVals(n) And 255)

Next
```

Comment: I don't have control of the incoming byte array though